# Result from querying Spotify API differs from identical query in web client

Tags: spotify

I've been using the Spotify API to query for an exact track by a given artist, making a GET request like so:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:"track+title"+artist:"artist+name"&type=track
```

(with the Authorization header *Bearer [access_token]*)

This works like expected in most cases, but for one track I got a problem: I'm trying to find the track [I Might Just Stay Home, with Shannon Lyon](https://open.spotify.com/track/7L8teKcMyOpIVDR0s6jAxq).

With my previously successful GET request adjusted to this tracks title and artist, this is what it should look like:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:"I+Might+Just+Stay+Home"+artist:"Shannon+Lyon"&type=track
```

This however yields zero results. And what makes it really strange: if I copy the exact same search query (*track:"I+Might+Just+Stay+Home"+artist:"Shannon+Lyon"*) into the [Spotify Web player](https://open.spotify.com/search/results/track%3A%22I%2BMight%2BJust%2BStay%2BHome%22%2Bartist%3A%22Shannon%2BLyon%22), I get the one search result I'm expecting. And I can also use the same query in the Spotify Desktop player, giving me the one result.

**So, the question is: What could be the reason to why I don't get a result from the API, whilst I get a result in both the web and desktop client using the exact same query?**

Comment: The clients don't seem to use the public API, instead they seem to use a private API of some sort, because this doesn't only happens with that track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One likely reason Potray has already given. The thing you see in the client comes from an internal API. They differ slightly from the public Web API.

Another more likely reason is just different availability in different countries and your two queries are for different countries, but you might not realize it.

When you search in the client, it is always a user who searches. A user is connected to a country. You can only play what is available in your country, so searching in the client only returns what you can play.

When you search with the Web API, you don't need to specify which Spotify user is searching. You also don't need to specify which country you want search results for.

Since the very beginning, not specifying a country, the search results would list tracks that were available in at least one country. Since last year, because of a bug, it instead defaults to the US. You can change country, but you can no longer search in all countries.

https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/194

Comment: You are absolutely correct! If I add *market=NO* to the request, I get the expected response. I guess that bug also explains why I have seen an example of a search result that, according to the API, should only be available in US, but still I found the song in the web player: the particular song probably exists in different versions with different market availability, but since the search defaults to *market=US* it appeared as it wasn't available in NO.

Comment: I would also argue that the documentation (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) is misleading: For the query parameter *market* it says "*Optional (...) **If** a country code is given, only artists, albums, and tracks with content playable in that market will be returned*". If market is omitted, I would thus expect results from *any* market being returned.

Comment: I have lost almost an hour trying to understand why the heck the results were different. Nothing is in the documentation. Another thing is that they say that the market parameter can be a list of country code strings, but they dont accept any that I try. Anyone on this?